# Prevent LAZY relationship exception

Tags: java, json, struts2

I'm having a big problem with JPA when I try serialize objects with JSON-Struts2 plugin.

I have the next exception:

> Exception Description: An attempt was made to traverse a relationship using indirection that had a null Session. This often occurs when an entity with an uninstantiated LAZY relationship is serialized and that lazy relationship is traversed after serialization. To avoid this issue, instantiate the LAZY relationship prior to serialization.

This is caused 'cause some parameters are lists and these lists have objects with other lists..

There is a way to inicializate all lists without modify the object facade?... or another option.. serializate only some parameters with JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using string list instead the whole object

Answer (score 2):

You can check if initializacion happened or force initializacion with [Hibernate.isInitialized](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#isInitialized%28java.lang.Object%29) and [Hibernate.initialize](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#initialize%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: I have resolved using only string to list my elements, trying to initialize all the lists is complicated :/ Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude parameters in struts-json-plugin. See http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/json-plugin.html#JSONPlugin-Excludingproperties

BTW if you going to use Hibernate#initialize method:

> Note: This only ensures intialization of a proxy object or collection; it is not guaranteed that the elements INSIDE the collection will be initialized/materialized.

Comment: This should be the better answer.